# kexec and USE_GRUB_CONFIG

Tags: linux, debian, grub, kexec

I find kexec very useful to speed-up the reboot of Linux servers.

One parameter into `/etc/default/kexec` is `USE_GRUB_CONFIG`.
This parameter is meant to "read Grub configuration file". But I don't understand what governs the choice between setting it to true or false.

What I understand: in Debian, the `/etc/init.d/kexec-load` file contains the code used to reboot with kexec. When `USE_GRUB_CONFIG` is set to true, then the Grub configuration file is read and its parameters are used to reboot.
If `USE_GRUB_CONFIG` is set to false, then the current kernel is reloaded with its current parameters.

So `USE_GRUB_CONFIG` set to true always reboot with the "normal" kernel.
And `USE_GRUB_CONFIG` set to false always reboot without changing anything, ignoring whatever could be done to Grub.

Then I deduce I should set it to true in order to take advantage of updates into Grub config.
So why is the default value false? Am I wrong somewhere, or do most admins prefer to slow-boot with special parameters then fast-reboot with them?

Answer (score 2):

With the default "false" the init script uses the kernel image und initrd from `/etc/default/kexec`. That is usually `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` - normally the last installed kernel.

When you set to "true", it is parsing the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file to find the default kernel image and initrd. Mostly that is the same. When you configure your grub to use a other kernel as default (e.g. a older one) kexec cannot recognise that except you set the option to "true".

Comment: Your answer is just a rewrite of the question, giving no usefull information.